# Probability problem

Tags: probability

Question:

> Let's say that I have $23$ people in my workplace. What is the probability that $2$ people in my workplace have the same birthday? Please answer in exact form with all decimal points that are implied.

I am sort of confused and would like to find the solution. If I could get a step-by-step solution, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: 100%....? o_O..

Comment: It is not $100$ percent! Be serious right now!

Comment: I am serious. All 23 people that are in your workplace share the same workplace... Yours. o_o"

Comment: @Shahar was making a bit of a joke, but all the same Jrachman, look at what you actually wrote, I'm sure it's not what you meant to write.

Comment: right! sorry Shahar! My bad

Comment: Ridiculous question! @Shahar Yes!

Comment: i just changed it Frank. If that makes you feel better.

Comment: @Jrachman Okay now you changed. 'ight the way you approach this is using binomial pdf. Did you learn that?

Comment: `binompdf(23,1/365,2)=1.7927%`. I think.

Comment: This is a famous problem, if you Google "birthday probability 23" you will get lots of links - in fact nearly 4 million when I did it ;-)

Comment: oH WOW. Do you a equation to formulate this problem? If you post it as an answer, I will +1 it and make it the answer if I think it is right?

Comment: @Jrachman See my answer.

Comment: Pretty good. However I have to wait for others to answer as well.

Comment: @Jrachman Do you mean at least 2 people or exactly 2 people? More common is the "at least".

Comment: exactly 2 people

Comment: Please don't modify old questions into new ones. Your new question should be posted as a new question.

Comment: They blocked my questions

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Wikipedia

> $p(n)$ is the probability of at least two of the n people sharing a
>   birthday. It is easier to first calculate the probability $\bar p(n)$
>   that all $n$ birthdays are different. According to the pigeonhole
>   principle, $p(n)$ is zero when $n > 365$. When $n ≤ 365$:
>   $$\begin{align*} \bar p(n) &= 1 \times \left(1-\frac{1}{365}\right)
>  \times \left(1-\frac{2}{365}\right) \times \cdots \times
>  \left(1-\frac{n-1}{365}\right)=\\\\ &= { 365 \times 364 \times \cdots
>  \times (365-n+1) \over 365^n }= { 365! \over 365^n (365-n)!} =
>  \frac{n!\cdot{365 \choose
> > n}}{365^n}=\\\\&=\frac{_{365}P_n}{365^n}\end{align*}$$where '!' is the
>   factorial operator, $\textstyle {365 \choose n}$ is the binomial
>   coefficient and ${_{k}P_r}$ denotes permutation. The equation
>   expresses the fact that the first person has no one to share a
>   birthday, the second person cannot have the same birthday as the first
>   $(364/365)$, the third cannot have the same birthday as the first two
>   $(363/365)$, and in general the nth birthday cannot be the same as any
>   of the $n − 1$ preceding birthdays. The event of at least two of the
>   $n$ persons having the same birthday is complementary to all n
>    birthdays being different. Therefore, its probability $p(n)$ is $$p(n)= 1 - \bar p(n)$$ This probability surpasses $1/2$ for $n = 23$ (with value about $50.7%$).

More precisely $$p(23)=1-\frac{23!\cdot \dbinom{365}{23}}{365^{23}}=0.507297234323986$$

Answer (score 0):

In a group of $23$ people there are $$ {23 \choose 2} = \dfrac{23 \cdot 22}{2} = 253 $$
Distinct combinations of pairing the workers/employees. Can you take it from here?

Comment: hey. Remember. +1 me. +1 you.